# Whats wrong with this circuit?

Tags: voltage-divider

I need an output of 882.3 mV in the highlighted node. According to my calculations the output must be that with Vin=15, R1=17K and R2=1k. So there must be something wrong with how the circuit is wired. What I’m not doing right?

[image: circuit]

Comment: The Vin(-) is the same impedance as Vin(+) ( ground 0 ohms) due to negative feedback

Comment: ... so eliminate one of the two 1K's on either side of divider

Comment: Or double the value for both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's funny, I teach EE and I recently gave a circuit quite similar to this to my student. The problem here is all about matching impedance. Because of the inverting amp, you have a virtual ground on the negative port of the op-amp. That virtual ground is the root cause of your impedance problem along with closely matched resistors.

With a small redrawing you can create a small model of what is going on: 17k in series with two 1k resistor in parallel that forms a voltage divider. Thus, you're input impedance of your op-amp is greatly reduced.

Vout = 1k//1k / (1k//1k + 17k) * 15 = 0.5 / (0.5 + 17) * 15 = 428.57 mV

To correct this you can either A) put a voltage follower between the voltage divider and the 1k resistor of the summing amp or B) increase all the 1k resistor of the summing amp to a much greater value. E.G: 30k.

30k // 1k = 960 ohm for the lower equivalent resistor.
 0.96 / (0.96 + 17) * 15 = 801.7 mV

You could increase the summing amp resistors even more if you really want to push the theory to the limit. But, most often you try to keep feedback resistors in the 1k-100k range.

Answer (score 0):

For this summing amplifier to work as expected, the sources have to have low impedance in comparison with 1k resistors.

The top source has low impedance, but the bottom source does not.

As a result, the voltage coming from the top source modifies the voltage coming from the bottom source.

To fix this, you can insert a voltage follower (which has a low output impedance) between the bottom source (17k/1k divider) and 1k resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this?

It is the output result ( gain and offset) that counts.

> an output of 882.3 mV in the highlighted node

??   =  - 882.3 mV  + 15/2V output from other path  ??

It is not the intermediate path that counts, but the combination of R ratio * R4/Rin(equiv)

**No buffer** is needed but you must define your gain properly and compensate for gain variation from R ratios and Req resistance.

This is not a fix, but a reason why your assumptions were wrong.

If you wanted to subtract 882.3 from the output then you should compute correctly, eliminate R1,R2,R3 and while R1=17k is the correct value!!

If the end-goal was to contribute  -882.3mV to output from 15V input

then -R4/R1 * 15V =  -882.3mV    with R4=1k
then R1=1k * 15V / 0.8823V= 17k  so R2 is removed and R3=0
[image]